# access TreeView from WPF .xaml in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I need help accessing in C# a TreeView created in .xaml.
I'm creating a simple TreeView that will collect all "Layers" from a document, and populate the TreeView with their names and other properties.
As a start point, I just want the names, then I'll add more properties.

The .xaml is as follows:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAlpha"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        Title=" Document Structure" Height="600" MinHeight="600" MaxHeight="600" Width="400" MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid x:Name="gridDocumentStructure" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <Menu Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Background="#FF3C4B64" Foreground="White">
            <MenuItem Header="Search" />
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Height="25" Click="buttonCloseDocumentStructureWindow_Click"/>
        </Menu>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewDocumentStructure" x:FieldModifier= "public" Background="#FFEBEBEB" Margin="10,35,10,10">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In C# I have:

```cs
// all necessary using statements and the two below, that are specific thar I need in this method
using static TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow;
using static DocumentLayers.LayerManagerWindow;
...
```

and an event for a button as below:

```cs
public static void DocumentStructure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (documentStructureWindow == null)
    {
        documentStructureWindow = new TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow();
        documentStructureWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        documentStructureWindow.Activate();
    }
    var tds = new TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow.gridDocumentStructure.TreeViewDocumentStructure();
    System.Type canvasType = typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Canvas);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (UIElement uie in TestWPFAlpha.MainWindow.canvasGrid.Children)
    {
        if (uie.GetType() == canvasType && count > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Layers[count - 1].Name);
            TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
            // Layers are from DocumentLayers.LayerManagerWindow
            newChild.Header = Layers[count - 1].Name;
            tds.Items.Add(newChild);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

At line 49

```
var tds = new TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow.gridDocumentStructure.TreeViewDocumentStructure();
```

I get the error:

> The type name 'gridDocumentStructure' does not exist in the type 'DocumentStructureWindow'

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this what you want to have:
`var tds = new TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow().TreeViewDocumentStructure;
`?

Comment: You can reach it directly via it's name. No need to make this chain through the grid. And actually that doesn't work, while the `TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow().gridDocumentStructure` part returns an object of type Grid, which of course has no definition for  TreeViewDocumentStructure

Comment: @tretom - thank you! - reaching directly via it's name is what I want - but I could not make it work - can you point to an example?

Answer (score 0):

An example as you requested. It's just a basic thing using code behind

the window with the tree view:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFAlpha.DocumentStructureWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFAlpha"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="gridDocumentStructure" x:FieldModifier="public">
    <Menu Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Background="#FF3C4B64" Foreground="White">
        <MenuItem Header="Search" />
        <MenuItem Header="Close" Height="25" Click="buttonCloseDocumentStructureWindow_Click"/>
    </Menu>
    <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewDocumentStructure" x:FieldModifier= "public" Background="#FFEBEBEB" Margin="10,35,10,10">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

it creates a new window:

```
usings...;

namespace TestWPFAlpha
{
    public partial class DocumentStructureWindow : Window
    {
        public DocumentStructureWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var newWin = new Window1(this);
            newWin.Show();  

        }
    }
}
```

and the `newWin` has a button, which does what I think you would like to achieve:

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private DocumentStructureWindow _documentStructureWindow;

    public Window1(DocumentStructureWindow documentStructureWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _documentStructureWindow = documentStructureWindow;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tds = _documentStructureWindow.TreeViewDocumentStructure;
        tds.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")} );
    }
}
```

see it here: [repo](https://github.com/tretom2121/TestWPFAlpha)

But I would recommend mvvm & commands instead of this code behind solution

Comment: thank you! I'll test your code and report back. Yes, I need to start diving into mvvm and follow the good practices.